# Should the ArcGIS Server Account be in the sysadmin SQL Server Role?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql

ArcGIS Server 10.2.2
SQL Server 2008 R2
DBO owned schema

I noticed that our ArcGIS Server account is in the sysadmin server role in our SQL Server 2008.  Does ArcGIS Server place the server account in that role by default?  Seems like too high level of permissions for the server account....

I think a problem I am having is stemming from this.  When I block connections to the database from ArcCatalog, the ArcGIS Server account is still able to connect while I'm doing database management tasks and it causes them to fail.

The screenshot below shows that the database is not accepting connections but the arcgis server account (GIS client machine) is still able to connect.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the account used to run the ArcGIS Server services? If so then no it shouldn't be in sysadmin. It shouldn't be able to connect to the geodatabase at all I don't think, there is no meed for it. Data should be published using database accounts that have read or edit privileges just on the data being served up.

Answer (score 1):

the ArcGIS Server account was somehow placed into the sysadmin role.  This gave the user DBO permission in the DB and allowed it to connect even when connections were blocked.

To solve the issue.  I mapped the ArcGIS Server account user to all of the DB's it would need to access with read and write privileges, I removed the AGS account from the sysadmin server role, then I had to re-boot the server for the changes to take effect.